# Imitate Matlab Matrix behavior

Tags: r

I Matlab it is possible to add elements vertically to vector even though their index scope far beyond just the next row. For example:

```
test = 1:5;
test(5,:) = 1:5;
```

will return.

```
1   2   3   4   5
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
1   2   3   4   5
```

Is there a nice, not so hacky way to do this in R?

Comment: Nope, that's not a doable thing in R. You can do that with vectors `v=1:3; v[6] = 4`, but nothing else. You'll probably want to read some introductory materials on R. Best practices are to preallocate your matrix.

Comment: `m <- matrix(0, 5, 5); m[1, ] <- 1:5; m[5, ] <- 1:5` not sure how that is useful though

Comment: So if I needed to absolutely do it I would need to write my own function which handles all special cases?

Comment: @rawr the thing is that I rebuilding a algorithm from Matlab which dynamically builds matrices. So I don't know beforehand how big my matrix will grow.

Comment: Well, I think this is going to be a case where directly porting code from one language to another is going to yield poor results, because growing objects in R is frequently _very_ slow. Even pre-allocating with a generous overestimate will often be more efficient than growing them in R. But probably the entire strategy of the code needs to be adapted to the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although joran is probably right about altering your procedure when switching to R, you could exploit the fact that indexing a vector results in enlarging too, as Frank noted in the comments. Taking advantage that matrices are vectors with a "dim" attribute and -for convenience- using the by-column storage of matrices, you could use something like:

```
add_col = function(x, col, value)
{
    nr = NROW(x)
    nc = if(col > NCOL(x)) col else NCOL(x)

    i1 = nr * (col - 1) + 1
    i2 = i1 + length(value) - 1
    x[i1:i2] = value

    length(x) = nr * nc
    dim(x) = c(nr, nc)

    return(x)
}

test = 1:5
add_col(test, 3, 1:3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1   NA    1
#[2,]    2   NA    2
#[3,]    3   NA    3
#[4,]    4   NA   NA
#[5,]    5   NA   NA
t(add_col(add_col(test, 3, 1:3), 6, 4:1))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[3,]    1    2    3   NA   NA
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[6,]    4    3    2    1   NA
```

This might be a bit hacky but is not much slower than, just, indexing a vector out of bounds:

```
X = seq_len(1e5)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(add_col(X, 1e2, seq_along(X)), 
                               t(add_col(X, 1e2, seq_along(X))), #with a transpose
                               "[<-"(X, (1e7 - (length(X) - 1)):1e7, seq_along(X)), #just vector out-of-bounds indexing
                               times = 50)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                                                    expr      min       lq   median        uq       max neval
#                           add_col(X, 100, seq_along(X)) 34.79408 40.02492 45.61020  63.24266  78.48069    50
#                        t(add_col(X, 100, seq_along(X))) 79.81389 84.06544 87.57906 102.75845 110.72842    50
# `[<-`(X, (1e+07 - (length(X) - 1)):1e+07, seq_along(X)) 17.25123 18.06138 21.48956  24.69084  48.91988    50

identical(c(add_col(X, 1e2, seq_along(X))), "[<-"(X, (1e7 - (length(X) - 1)):1e7, seq_along(X)))
#[1] TRUE
```